# Check if all children of div have class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if all children of different divs (with same id/class) have the class active. A typical if/else sentence but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

See the example here, this would be true as all children have the same class:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
</div>
```

And this would be false as not all children have the same class:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

There are many divs alike but the amount of children vary. It's important that it's 100% of the children that have the class before it is true.

How would you make the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to check if all children of a certain div element have the class `active` or if all children of a certain div element have the same class regardles of its name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it!
Simplest one being:

```js
if($('.parent .child.active').length === $('.parent .child').length){
 //return true
  console.log('true');
}
else{
 //return false
  console.log('false');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `length` comparison or [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
let parent1 = document.querySelector(".parent1"),
  parent2 = document.querySelector(".parent2");

if (parent1.children.length == parent1.querySelectorAll(".active").length) {
  console.log("All children have the class “active”.");
}

// or

if (Array.from(parent1.children).every(child => child.classList.contains("active"))) {
  console.log("All children have the class “active”.");
}

// similarly, for .parent2:

console.log(parent2.children.length == parent2.querySelectorAll(".active").length);
console.log(Array.from(parent2.children).every(child => child.classList.contains("active")));
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="child active"></div>
  <div class="child active"></div>
  <div class="child active"></div>
  <div class="child active"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child active"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child active"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can count elements with `:not` selector:

```
var result = $('.parent').find('.child:not(.active)').length === 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var flag = true;
$('.parent').find('div.child').each(function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
    flag = false;
});

if(flag)
  console.log("All Child divs have active class");
else
  console.log("All child divs doesn't have active class");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
</div>
```

One more example

```js
var flag = true;
$('.parent').find('div.child').each(function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
    flag = false;
});

if(flag)
  console.log("All Child divs have active class");
else
  console.log("All child divs doesn't have active class");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: While not wrong, the each is a bit overkill for such simple functionality :)

Answer (score 1):

You can  select the items you want and also filter that set for your extra class. Those sets should be the same length

```
let $children = $('.parent').children('.child');
console.log( $children.length == $children.filter('.active').length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count all the elements with the `child` class and compare it to the number of objects having the `active` class. If they match, you're good to go.

```
if ($('.parent .child').length === $('.parent .child.active')) {
    // everything good
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(".parent .child").length === $(".parent .child.active").length){/*true*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `:not` css property

```js
var childs = $('.parent').find('div.child:not(.active)');
if (childs.length > 0) {
console.log('not all active')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with a for loop and jquery =>

```
 var childs = $('.parent').find('.child');

 for (var i=0;i<=childs.length;i++)
      if (!childs[i].hasClass('active'))
          return false
 return true
```

Otherwise :

```
  return ($('.parent').find('.child').length === $('.parent').find('.child.active').length)
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. Nothing happens: https://jsfiddle.net/kq2tckrg/
This code just doesnt print either of the texts in console. I made one parent with alle active childs and one without.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do a count of children with selectors

```js
var $parent1 = $('.parent');
var $parent2 = $('.parent2');

var areAllActive = function ($node) {
  var $childrenActive = $node.children('div.active');
  console.log($childrenActive.length);
  var $allChildren = $node.children('div');
  console.log($allChildren.length);
  
  return $childrenActive.length === $allChildren.length;
};

console.log(areAllActive($parent1));
console.log(areAllActive($parent2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child active"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```